# obtener año de nacimiento a traves de la edad mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Hola buenas me gustaria obtener el año de nacimiento de una persona a traves de su edad para ello tengo el siguiente codigo pero no me sirve:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS veterinario2;
CREATE DATABASE veterinario2;
USE veterinario2;
CREATE TABLE MASCOTAS (
    nombre VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    especie VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    raza VARCHAR(15),
    sexo ENUM('M', 'H') NOT NULL,
    edad INT NOT NULL
) engine=innodb;

INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('michi', 'gato', 'pardo', 'M', 19);
INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('firulais', 'perro', 'labrador', 'H', 20);
INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('doggy', 'perro', 'chiguagua', 'H', 22);
INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('catty', 'gato', 'mixto', 'H', 18);
INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('perrete', 'perro', 'bulldog', 'M', 25);
INSERT INTO MASCOTAS VALUES ('obli', 'pajaro', 'canario', 'H', 21);

SELECT nombre FROM MASCOTAS;
SELECT especie FROM MASCOTAS;
SELECT nombre FROM MASCOTAS;
SELECT sexo FROM MASCOTAS
WHERE sexo='H';
SELECT nombre FROM MASCOTAS;
SELECT FLOOR(SYSDATE()-edad) FROM MASCOTAS;
```

Si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo porque me da esta salida:

```
+-----------------------+
| FLOOR(SYSDATE()-edad) |
+-----------------------+
|        20230123103524 |
|        20230123103520 |
|        20230123103522 |
|        20230123103523 |
|        20230123103521 |
|        20230123103517 |
+-----------------------+
```

Muchas gracias de antemano;

Comment: Pero una **Fecha de Nacimiento** es un dato exacto, como es que pretendes averiguar la fecha de nacimiento con solo la edad? Quizás estés planteando mal el problema y lo que quieras obtener es el año de nacimiento. Puedes dar contexto y [edit] tu pregunta?

Comment: Si obviamente solo quería obtener una fecha aproximada como puede ser el año de nacimiento es para un ejercicio

Comment: No, no es obvio porque son dos cosas muy diferentes. Una cosa es una Fecha de Nacimiento y otra es el Año de Nacimiento.

Comment: Ok ahora lo cambio sin problemas

Comment: Ya esta gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido averiguarlo, quedaria asi el codigo:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval edad year) FROM MASCOTAS;
```

Con eso esta usando las funciones `date_sub()` y `now()`, `date_sub()` se usa para aislar un dato de la fecha por ejemplo el año, los minutos, el mes etc... por lo que lo usamos en la fecha actual la cual se saca de la funcion `now()` y luego con interval se aisla para restarse a la columna edad de la tabla mascotas